# How to change color of input range slider with tailwind css?

Tags: range, slider, tailwind-css

Wish you are having a wonderful day,

I'm currently trying to apply some color to a simple slider range.

```
<Input class="range pr-6 bg-red-500" 
                    type="range" 
                    value="0" min="0" 
                    max="1000" 
                    onChange="rangeSlide(this.value)" 
                    onmousemove="rangeSlide(this.value)"></Input>
```

It doesn't work at all to change the color like this, I also tried with text and border class.

I made some research and assume I should use this to change the slider bar : -webkit-slider-thumb

Like this :

```
.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  background: #00fd0a;
}
```

However I wish to only use tailwind and dont apply style with pure css. if anyone have any insight to give me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not for sure but does this answer your question? Check the docs here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support#vendor-prefixes

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I didn't knew this, + the can i use it seems super helpful to track brower compatibility. I finally got the answer I wanted by search more inside the doc

Answer (score 21):

Here is what works for me, using `accent-<color>-<number>` :

```
<Input class="range pr-6 accent-red-500" 
                    type="range" 
                    value="0" min="0" 
                    max="1000" 
                    onChange="rangeSlide(this.value)" 
                    onmousemove="rangeSlide(this.value)"></Input>
```

Also, link to the documentation if someone pass by and need more info : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/accent-color

Comment: "oninput" event

Answer (score 4):

Also found this approach:

```
 <input type="range" 
        class="appearance-none bg-transparent [&::-webkit-slider-runnable-track]:rounded-full [&::-webkit-slider-runnable-track]:bg-black/25 [&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:h-[50px] [&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:w-[50px] [&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:rounded-full [&::-webkit-slider-thumb]:bg-purple-500" 
 />
```

Comment: How's the browser support for this?